# How to change the format of a date picker in materialize design

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Want to change the date format in materialize design date picker. Like now it is like displaying as Dec 02, 2019 in this format but I want to display like 02-12-2019 this.

Following is the sample code which is had tried,

```
<div class="row">
  <form action="" class="col s12 m8 offset-m2 l6 offset-l3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field">
        <input type=text name="bdate" id="bdate" class="datepicker" required>
        <label for="bdate">Birthday</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field">
        <input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="validate">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hope this will help you. :)
https://medium.com/@amandeepkochhar/angular-material-datepicker-set-custom-date-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format-5c0f4340e57

Comment: I am using the jquery not the Angular.

Comment: Here follow this [materialize datepicker](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html). You can update `format` attribute to list your date to any format.